How to make a concrete built home warm in winter?
I'm Nepalese. I can import stuffs from India and China.
I suffer from Raynaud's phenomenon. My feet and palm are extremely cold. The problem that I am trying to solve is I want mobility(use laptop, type keyboard etc) while I am warm. So that I can spend my time at home learning new stuffs etc.
Currently I have this foot warmer

I stay at floor and study/use laptop in a bed study table like this:

My room has furniture like bed, cupboard, bookshelf table etc. The windows are sealed, so as the doors. The floor is also sealed. So, I suppose the room is decently insulated.
Can you recommend any heating mechanism to keep myself warm? I do layering, wear woolen socks, gloves. However, due to Raynaud's the cold feet and palm continue to exist even though other body parts are warm.

This isn't a home improvement question per the [help]. It's more about appliances and furnishings. (Your title asks about making your home warmer, but your post asks about making you warmer.) Good luck.

As with a home built from any material, insulation is key, so I would not make the assumption that it's decently insulated. More insulation is the typical solution.
For common concrete construction in cold climates, an external insulation solution (typically with a stucco coat over sheet insulation) is usually the best way to go, since it moves the concrete thermal mass inside the insulation.
